# Sumar campos dentro de bucle foreach

Tags: php, mysql, bucles, foreach

Sucede que tengo que sumar el valor de los registro de un bucle foreach por columna, es decir, el array a recorrer viene desde una consulta sql que es formulada a gusto por el usuario y esta es recibida por en formulario y pasada a el foreach que genera la tabla, lo que viene al tema, es sumar todos los que sean columnas numéricas y mostrar resultado.

Ejemplo:

Columnas: Nombre - Apellido - Colación - Movilización - Sueldo

Según lo anterior se generara un foreach que rellenara una tabla con esas columnas, a la cual debe salir el total de cada columna que sea numérica.

Actualmente uso el siguiente código:

```
foreach($resultado as $r){
    $Contenido .= "<tr>";

        foreach($r as $rd){
            if(is_numeric($rd)) {
                $Contenido .= "<td class='content'>".$rd."</td>";
            } else {
                $Contenido .= "<td class='content'>".$rd."</td>";
            }

        }

    $Contenido .= "</tr>";
}
```

Esto me sirve para conocer si un valor es numero, la situación es sumar todos aquellos que sean de la misma columna.

Recuerdo que no siempre es la misma columna, ya que esta es al azar para el sistema.

Comment: como creas la consulta? por que usas deos foreach?

Comment: La consulta es realizada por un método al estilo PDO, donde el resultado de la consulta es guardado dentro de un array ($registros) y este método es recibido por $resultado el cual contiene el array y por ende se genera doble foreach.

Comment: Solo contenido es numerico? como sabes que $rd corresponde a que campo?

Comment: Codigo Triste, no puedes devolver en la consulta una columna que equivalga al SUM total? te ahorrara mucho trabajo y rendimiento.

Comment: Contenido es la variable que se usa para mostrar los resultados, los cuales se acomodan a la tabla que se quiere mostrar... No puedo devolver en la consulta una columna con suma, dado que al usuario antes de esta función selecciona que columna quiere visualizar y este la selecciona con un checkbox, el cual se manda al método que ejecuta la sentencia y trae los resultados, siempre todo estara disponible para que el usuario sea el que escoja que ver, momentos donde todo pueda ser columnas numericas o otros donde son campos string....

Answer (score 1):

Si el total no viene en tu consulta `SQL` tendrías que recorrer todo el arreglo para sumar la columnas y al final agregar como una fila a tu tabla

```
$sueldo =0; // y las otras variables que deseas que se sumen
    foreach ($resultado as $key ) {
        $sueldo = $sueldo+$key['sueldo'];
        // igual para las otras variables
    }

 echo $sueldo; //aquí imprimir la fila de acuerdo a tu necesidad
```